# Shell script to read two values from file and insert them into a command

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file, say, `input.txt` and I want to run a command and write the output to another text file, say, `output.txt`. I need to read values from `input.txt`, each value is in a line, then I need to insert them in the command then write the result in `output.txt` file. I tried the following and it works fine with me:

```
for i in `cat input.txt`; do command -m $i -b 100; echo $i; >> output.txt; done
```

Now, I need to make some improvements over this but I have little experience in Linux so I need some help.

What I need to do is:
1) Before each command result, I want to insert the value of `i` separated by comma. For example:

```
i1,result1 
i2,result2
i3,result3
```

2) I need to change the second fixed value that I used in my command from a fixed value (100) to a value read from `input.txt`. So, the new input file which contains two values, say, `newinput.txt` is as the following:

```
i1,value1
i2,value2
i3,value3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in bash:

```
IFS=','
while read i val; do
  echo -n "$i,"
  command $i $val
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This is what I get: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'`

Comment: When I removed the `;` before do, I got: `while: command not found`

Comment: I solved the issue. I was writing the script in the terminal. When I wrote it to a file and then execute it, it worked.

Comment: @user1810868 Typing the script to the terminal is not the issue.  Rather, the issue is (probably) that the shell you are using when entering text is a csh variant.